# How to upload to Apple's My Apps from a Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I specifically need help getting the app build into my apps. I am so new to the MAC ecosystem. I need to get my app build from my windows 10 box (parallels) running VS2017/Xamarin Forms project uploaded to My Apps. What i have found is helpful if you are using xcode on the mac.

I have read tons of pages and help files and with all of that what I have includes:

- created an app in VS2017/Xamarin that runs happily on the emulator from the MAC (MacBook Pro)
- purchased the app dev subcription from apple
- created a Production certificate (I don't need this yet but I was in there so...)
- created a Development certificate
- created a key pair from the Dev cert (that show up in the keychain)
- created an App Group
- created my app's placeholder under My Apps on App Store Connect
- added my iPhone to devices via connecting to the Mac getting the UDID from iTunes
- created a development provisioning profile for my iPhone (Not sure how this helps my testflight plight)

Assumptions

- You must submit for review the same way for both TestFlight and Prod release to the actual store.
- You don't need to open the app in xcode outside Xamarin 
  There is a tool or concept I am missing out on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows

Comment: I am walking the dog on that right now @Jason. I hope it fills the holes in.

Comment: This page is huge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development outside of Xcode, you will want to use Apple's [Application Loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdS673accdb) App to upload your app to App Store Connect.

Comment: I believe that this is the tail end of the puzzle. I initially thought that this was part of xcode.  Now I have to get the project set right.

Comment: Without this piece it would have taken much longer for me to figure out the whole puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6613812/matt-weinecke) below his *correct answer to my actual question* above, I needed to get the project right to get to that point.

[image]

Here are the more intimate details for the lurkers. I hope this helps some of you.

I was getting, or trying, to get all of this in place manually instead of letting VS do it's work getting this stuff together while I got to coding. [FastLane](https://fastlane.tools/) FTW

- Open the account management window, go to *Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts*
- Add your AppleID
- Click on your appleID
- Click the add button
- Select your id in the lower text area
  [image]
- then add your distro cert. As is proper you deploy to TestFlight as a prod release.
  [image]

### Then get over to to your iOS project properties:

Make sure that your project is outputting an IPA. (Not Beer ;) ) 
[image]

These are my settings that worked. There *could* be other configurations that work as well. 
[image]

I never get the automatic provisioning to work. And while this bundle signing settings look like it will not work, it does. I have received my apple approval for beta and users are in testflight.
[image]

Also, make sure you update the version of the app in the plist for subsequent releases. This change is not carried through from the AssemblyInfo.cs as one might expect. viola.

[image]

---

If you see this **during debug** make sure your debug version has **Developer (Automatic)** set for your debug settings.
[image: SNAFU Msg]
[image: Debug Only]

---

FWIW - My VS2017:
[image]

While this does not perfectly match the info @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows it worked for me. That page was key to the solution and deserves citing. Your mileage may vary.

If I missed something please reach out and I will update this.